# Can we define $N_t:=\int_0^t \operatorname{sign}(B_s) \mathrm{d}s$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a Wiener process in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{sign}$ the signum function. Is the process, defiended as stochastic integral or pathwise Lebesgue integral ,
$$N_t:=\int_0^t \operatorname{sign}(B_s) \mathrm{d}s$$ well-defined? I think as a pathwise Lebesgue integral it should be well defined since it is a measurable. But what about the stochastic integral? Is $\operatorname{sign}(B)$ predictable? What can we say beyond this about the process $N$? The expectation of the process $N$ should be $0$ and it should be of finite variation on compact sets. Are the further interesting properties?

Comment: Yes, it might be a stochastic integral since the identity $I$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ is a semimartingale. But for this case we also have to check if $\operatorname{sing}(B)$ is predictable and $I$-integrable. The later should be no problem, since it is a bounded process. Furthermore there is a theorem which says in that case it conincides a.s. with the pathwise Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Since $B$ is predictable and $\operatorname{sing}$ is measureable, the process $\operatorname{sing}(B)$ should be predictable. So the question, wether we can define it as stochastic integral should be clear.

Comment: sign, not sing.

Comment: yes, little typing and copy paste mistake.

Comment: I don't get what your question actually is, since $\sign$ is measurable, and $B$ is continuous (a.s) then the Lebesgue integral is well defined for any interval $[0,t]$. What about the stochastic integral? do you mean $\int_0^t \sign (B_s)dB_s$?

Comment: Most of the several questions are meanwhile answered. One of them was the verfication of the thoughts, that it is well definied as a Lebesgue integral, which was done by you. Thanks. The next question, wether it is well definied as a stochastic integral, was answered in the comments above - provided it is right. By stochastic integral I mean here a integral regarding the semimatingle integration theory and not the Itô-theory, which is a special case of this. So $\int_0^t \operatorname{sign}(B_s) \mathrm{d}s$ was no typing mistake. I asked this because I wasn't sure if this is possible.

Comment: The next two questions are the verification of my thoughts regarding the expectation and the finite variation, since I'm not sure about this. Furthermore I hoped someone might know further interesting properties about this process, since it looks like a process that someone might has seen somewhere before - e.g. in a calculus. For me this process is so interesting, since it looks like "normalized" brownian motion, i. e. it takes the sign of the process but always grows with the same rate.